# Database associations causing issues in db migration with postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've been making a basic schema for a rails app but when I try to migrate it using `rails db:migrate`, it gives me some weird association errors that I'm not sure what's causing.

```rb
== 20211001092658 CreateDevelopers: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:developers)
   -> 0.0076s
== 20211001092658 CreateDevelopers: migrated (0.0077s) ========================

== 20211001093122 CreateMessages: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:messages)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teams" does not exist
/home/nero/Projects/SMS-Rails/db/migrate/20211001093122_create_messages.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teams" does not exist
/home/nero/Projects/SMS-Rails/db/migrate/20211001093122_create_messages.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teams" does not exist
/home/nero/Projects/SMS-Rails/db/migrate/20211001093122_create_messages.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I've been having a few issues setting up Postgres on my machine but I figured most of it would be solved after I created the role, password and database.

Migration files:

```rb
#developers

class CreateDevelopers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :developers do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :mobile

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#teams

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :dept_name
      t.string :dev_ids, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#messages

class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :team, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I renamed the files like `1_create_teams` and so on and tried migrating but only the `developer` model gets migrated. The schema file gets created but the other two are missing. I'm trying to rollback but it just tells me that the model already exists.

Comment: If you don't have any valuable data in database you can just re-create database. Call `rails db:drop && rails db:create && rails db:migrate`.

Comment: Ok, I must be going about this the wrong way. It dropped the tables but I'm getting an `PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create database`. Am I setting up the roles in postgres incorrecly or am I supposed to be in psql mode or something?

Comment: Looks like it’s a problem with roles and permissions in postgres

Comment: I got it! Apparently had to alter the user role to be allowed to create dbs for some reason. Might need a refresher on postgres after this. Thank you all so much for helping out!

Comment: Protip - don't make the misstake of using `t.string :dev_ids, array: true, default: []`. Create a real join table instead (`rails g model membership team:references developer:references`) so that you can use assocations and foreign key constraints to maintain referential integrity as well as can write sane join queries. Array columns are basically just the modern equivilent to storing stuff in comma seperated strings and are just as much of a violation of 1-NF.